# pandas: getting scalar value by iloc

Tags: python, pandas

upgraded from 10.1 to 13.1, a lot issues...

with 10.1 i used something like stock.iloc[-1:]['Close'] to get the scalar value.

now with 13.1 it doesn't work, it gets me like:

Out:

Date
2014-02-26 118.2
Name: Close, dtype: float64

it prefer using mixed positional and label as indexing the value, but .ix cannot handle index -1.

Comment: iloc was not introduced until 0.11; pls show a full example of what u are trying to do

Comment: it works now with using stock.iloc[-1]['Close'], what is the diff between [-1:] and [-1], i thought [-1:] is syntactic rightful than [-1] ... i used stock.ix[-1]['Close'] with 10.1 , but after the upgrade pandas 13.1 could not tolerate [-1] with .ix

Comment: ``[-1:]`` returns a slice, while ``[-1]`` is a scalar. You have to be very careful with ``ix``, see here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#fallback-indexing; this has been true since beginning of pandas, but docs are newer

Comment: tks. bit if [-1:] is a slice, then it is a subset of an array/series, [-1:]['label'] should be able to retrieve the element, while [-1] is a scalar, then [-1]['label'] shouldn't be wrong cuz scalar is not index based?!